# cakePhp - Access folder content inside webroot

Tags: javascript, php, css, cakephp

This is my desired structure:

```
-webroot/
    -css/
    -font/
    -img/
    -js/
    -new_folder/
        -file.css
        -another_new_folder/
             -file.js
```

How can i access `webroot/new_folder/file.css` and `webroot/new_folder/another_new_folder/file.js` inside a `.ctp` file, in order to generate both tags like this:

```
<link href="/new_folder/file.css">
<script src="/new_folder/another_new_folder/file.js">
```

without generating controllers, if possible.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
echo $this->Html->css('/new_folder/file');
    // webroot/new_folder/file.css
echo $this->Html->script('/new_folder/another_new_folder/file');
    // webroot/new_folder/another_new_folder/file.js
```

For css and script you can use following way

```
echo $this->Html->script('custom');
    // webroot/js/custom.js

echo $this->Html->script('otherdir/custom');
    // webroot/js/otherdir/custom.js


echo $this->Html->script('/otherdir/custom');
// webroot/otherdir/custom.js
```

For more please check [Linking to Javascript Files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-javascript-files) and [Linking to CSS Files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-css-files)

Comment: in this case, i need to change 
`'cssBaseUrl' => 'css/',` and `'jsBaseUrl' => 'js/',` to `'cssBaseUrl' => '',` and `'jsBaseUrl' => '',`in `config/app.php`?

Comment: if you place `/` before the url then it will take from `webroot` path

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
<?php echo $this -> Html -> css(array('/new_folder/file.css'));?>
```

js:

```
<?php echo $this -> Html -> script(array('/new_folder/another_new_folder/file.js'));?>
```

Comment: when i try this, the result is:
`<script src="/js/new_folder/another_new_folder/file.js"></script>`
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/new_folder/file.css"/>`
 
and, even if i put static url without using HtmlHelper, i receive a 
`Cake\Routing\Exception\MissingControllerException` error.